# Invalid cursor exception in 2nd iteration

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I am getting invalid cursor exception while iterating for 2nd time.

```
LOAD_TABLE_REF_CURSOR(V_TARIFF_TABLE_ROWS); -- V_TARIFF_TABLE_ROWS is a sys_refcursor.
```

when I am doing iteration like below.

```
LOAD_TABLE_REF_CURSOR(V_TARIFF_TABLE_ROWS);
    LOOP
        FETCH V_TARIFF_TABLE_ROWS INTO TAK_ROW;
        EXIT WHEN V_TARIFF_TABLE_ROWS%NOTFOUND;


    END LOOP;
```

The control inside the loop is going for 1st time fine and throwing exception as invalid cursor exactly at FETCH statement for the 2nd time.

Could someone tell whats wrong with 2nd iteration.

Comment: Please show a [complete, minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

`invalid cursor` error is produced when;
    FETCH cursor before OPENING the cursor.
    FETCH cursor after CLOSING the cursor.
    CLOSE cursor before OPENING the cursor.

```
LOAD_TABLE_REF_CURSOR(V_TARIFF_TABLE_ROWS);

open V_TARIFF_TABLE_ROWS;

    -- use V_TARIFF_TABLE_ROWS

close V_TARIFF_TABLE_ROWS;
```